"java.lang.SecurityException: cannot verify signature block file META-INF" from jarsigner after verifying jar it's just signed
I'm signing a jar using jarsigner, with a certificate chain (one that's using a HSM-backed private key on Azure, so i'm using https://ebourg.github.io/jsign/ for this.
jarsigner -verbose -J-cp -Jjsign-6.0.jar  -J--add-modules -Jjava.sql -providerClass net.jsign.jca.JsignJcaProvider -providerArg [azure-key-vault-name] -keystore NONE -storetype AZUREKEYVAULT -storepass $AZURE_ACCESS_TOKEN -certchain my-cert-chain.p7b my-jar.jar MyAlias

And jarsigner reports that the file is successfully signed:
updating: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
   adding: META-INF/MYALIAS.SF
   adding: META-INF/MYALIAS.RSA
   adding: com/ (with the actual directories)
   signing: com/ (with the actual classes)
jar signed.

Yet if I run jarsigner -verify myjar.jar (or open the jar with the Keystore Explorer tool) on that jar file straight after, I get this error: jarsigner: java.lang.SecurityException: cannot verify signature block file META-INF/MYALIAS (attached is a fuller stacktrace that Keystore Explorer gives me:

I've extracted the signed jar, renamed MYALIAS.RSA to a .p7b file, and Keystore explorer opens that fine, and the certificate chain in it is identical to the one i'm signing with- so what's going on?
I'm on Windows, with OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-17.0.9.8.1 (build 17.0.9+8-LTS), and it does this no matter what jar i'm signing.

I suggest you get OpenSSL, if you don't already have it e.g. in a WSL instance or git4win, or copy the .RSA and .SF files to some other system that does, and check openssl cms -verify -in RSAfile -inform d -content SFfile (add -CAfile root.pem if it's not in the default truststore) and openssl asn1parse -in RSAfile -inform d -i
